# Integrate Datatables plugin with the help of D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, datatables

I've been on this for hours - I can't figure out which part of my code that is wrong.I managed to make and display a proper table when I run my code but I want to be able to make my table like this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194916/Enhancing-HTML-tables-using-a-JQuery-DataTables-pl#Introduction

So I try using Datatable jquery plugin. So far no luck. Please, I would greatly appreciate your help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>


<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 2px black solid;
        font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px black solid;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>



 <div id="container"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">



  d3.text("file.csv", function (datasetText) {

  var rows = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);

  var tbl = d3.select("#container")
    .append("table")
    .attr("id","tableID");


// headers
  tbl.append("thead").append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(rows[0])
    .enter().append("th")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });

   // data
    tbl.append("tbody")
    .selectAll("tr").data(rows.slice(1))
    .enter().append("tr")

    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d){return d;})
    .enter().append("td")
    .text(function(d){return d;})



   });

     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#tableID').dataTable();
     } );


</script>
 </body>
 <html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong with your table, or make a fiddle?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the table. It's just when I call the $('#tableID').dataTable(); - nothing happened / no manipulation happened. @Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at the browser console for any errors and mention them here, if you can't interpret them by yourself. It says that the dataTables function is unknown, which is caused by the fact, that you include two different jquery versions. I'm guessing the 2nd include of jquery replaces the inital namespace with the dataTables plugin defined.
2. The dataTables plugin should not be called outside the CSVs callback function. If loading the csv & execution the callback takes too long, the `$('#tableID').dataTable();` is called before the DOM is even there. Move it inside the callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    d3.text("file.csv", function (datasetText) {
        // draw d3 elements
        $('#tableID').dataTable();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I managed to get it working. I removed one of the JQuery versions.

Comment: I was wondering if I can ask another question - I have this line  d3.text("file.csv", function (datasetText) {...} If I were to integrate somesort of file browser, how do I go about it?